# Android DownloadManager always returning 404

Tags: java, android, kotlin, download-manager

Trying to use android's DownloadManager service but always getting a 404 as reason.
Here is the code that queues up a request :

```
val downloadManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
                val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)

                request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
                request.setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);

                //TODO : do we need to wait here ??
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(baseSessionActivity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 0);
                }


                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS , File(absoluteURL).name)

                headers?.forEach { pair ->
                    request.addRequestHeader(pair.first, pair.second)
                }

                return downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

and then here is the code that reads the status after i receive a ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE intent :

```
    val query = DownloadManager.Query() 
query.setFilterById(downloadId) 
val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager 
val cursor = downloadManager.query(query) 

cursor?.let { 
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
var reasonIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON) 
var reason = cursor.getInt(reasonIndex) 
var status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))
```

I do not see the file on disk so the 404 is right. Please let me know if there is anything wrong in my code. Thanks

Comment: Well, the file is not there so you're getting a 404. What do you expect?

Comment: The file URL is valid. I can download it on chrome. I do not see the file having been downloaded on disk, thats what i mean by the last sentence.